# How to callOAuth2 password grant type REST API from Spring Boot using oauth2-client

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, oauth-2.0

I try to create a simple Spring Boot application to query a third party Rest API and write the response body to the console. The rest api is OAuth2 password grant type protected.

I can get an access_token using Postman on the token url by a POST request with client_id, client_secret, username, password and grant_type=password in the x-www-form-urlencoded body.

If i subsequently use the token as a bearer token with a GET request on the resource url i get the expected JSON.

My Spring Application looks as following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CraPocApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CraPocApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(WebClient webClient) {
        return args -> {
            String body = webClient.get()
                .uri("https://api.iot.cra.cz/cxf/api/v1/projects")
                .attributes(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.clientRegistrationId("custom-client"))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();

            System.out.println(body);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2 =
            new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(oauth2)
            .build();
    }
}
```

The client configuration is here:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
        ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .authorizationCode()
                .refreshToken()
                .clientCredentials()
                .password()
                .build();

        DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
            new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
}
```

and the application.yaml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          custom-client:
            client-id: iot-api-client
            client-secret: MY_CLIENT_SECRET
            authorization-grant-type: password
            username: MY_USERNAME
            password: MY_PASSWORD
            scope: read
        provider:
          custom-client:
            token-uri: https://sso.cra.cz/auth/realms/CRA/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

On running the application i get following trace

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-01-05T11:13:13.362+01:00 ERROR 67668 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: serverWebExchange cannot be null
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.lambda$authorize$4(DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.java:153) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET https://api.iot.cra.cz/cxf/api/v1/projects [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.lambda$authorize$4(DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.java:153) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4512) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2573) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2367) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2241) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilter.java:85) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4512) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:297) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:478) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2097) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2573) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2367) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2241) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilter.java:85) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4512) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.request(MonoZip.java:220) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2367) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2241) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4512) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4512) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1727) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at cz.tsb.crapoc.CraPocApplication.lambda$run$0(CraPocApplication.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$5(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:806) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:797) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at cz.tsb.crapoc.CraPocApplication.main(CraPocApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1728) ~[reactor-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at cz.tsb.crapoc.CraPocApplication.lambda$run$0(CraPocApplication.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$5(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:806) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:797) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at cz.tsb.crapoc.CraPocApplication.main(CraPocApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
```

I cannot find anything useful in the stack though.

Can anyone help?